# Inputing 5 row data,classifiying(predicting) 6th row in Keras LSTM

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, recurrent-neural-network

I want to input 5 row of a dataset to `LSTM` and classify 6th row of Y. I made the input by reshaping the data:

```
X = X.reshape(6000,5,5)
```

But how can I predict Y of 6th row? What shape Y should have? I read a lot and search a lot on Google,but honestly I couldn't understand the code because they customize their data before using them.

My full code:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder,MinMaxScaler
from keras.layers import Dense,RNN,LSTM,Activation,Dropout,SimpleRNN,Bidirectional
from keras.optimizers import RMSprop,Adam
from keras.wrappers.scikit_learn import KerasClassifier
from keras.models import Sequential
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv('./EURUSD_DATAFRAME.csv')
BinEncoder = LabelEncoder()
scalar = MinMaxScaler()

df['pos'] = df['pos'].astype('int')
dat = df.values




X = dat[0:30000,0:5]
Y = dat[0:6000,5]


X[:,4]= BinEncoder.fit_transform(X[:,4])
X[:,0:4] = scalar.fit_transform(X[:,0:4])
X[:,4] = X[:,4].astype('int')
Y = BinEncoder.fit_transform(Y)

X = X.reshape(6000,5,5)
#MODEL 3
 model = Sequential()
 model.add(LSTM(1024,input_shape=(5,5),return_sequences=True,kernel_initializer='normal'))
 #model.add(Activation('tanh'))
 model.add(Dropout(0.2))
 model.add(LSTM(512))
 model.add(Dropout(0.3))
 model.add(Dense(1))
 model.add(Activation('sigmoid'))
 model.compile(optimizer='adam',loss='binary_crossentropy',metrics=['accuracy'])
 model.fit(X,Y,batch_size=100,epochs=10,validation_split=0.2)
 p = model.predict(X)
# print(classifier.score(X,Y))
# ----
```

I am classifiying Y which is Encoded as 1 or 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, but I don't understand really what do you mean by this? Your input shape is (6000, 5, 5) and your output shape is (6000, 2)? So what do you mean by sixth row?

Comment: Classifier get 5 row of a data as input, then It predict(classify) the 6th row label.

Comment: I think I got it, you are inputting 5 features, rows and expecting the model to predict the label for 6th row. In this case you don't need to do anything, cause nn will find the mapping between your input x and labels y itself, cuz this is what they are made for

Comment: I was so confused about it that how can I predict 6th row label from previous 5 rows!!! Thank you  so much!!

Answer (score 1):

It's quite simple. Use built in keras function: Which will turn it into one hot representation, like [0, 1] and [1, 0]

```
 from keras.utils import to_categorical

 y = to_categorical(y, num_classes=2)
```

And change the number of units in the last dense layer to the num_classes, 2 in your case. And I think you should use softmax for classification instead of sigmoid. Also I would advice you to use 'relu' activation between your lstm layers or more advanced LeakyRelu

Comment: Thanks, one of my problem solved. And how can I input 5 row as input,and predict 6th?